# SSLException Bad Certificate

Tags: java, ssl, certificate, ubuntu-12.04, keytool

I've got a brief assignment for class which is to extend a simple Java server to support SSL on Ubuntu.

Ok, so to start, I did this:

private static SSLServerSocketFactory factory;

```
private static SSLServerSocket serverSocket;



public SimpleWebServer () throws Exception {          

//dServerSocket = new ServerSocket (PORT);  

factory = (SSLServerSocketFactory)SSLServerSocketFactory.getDefault();

serverSocket = (SSLServerSocket)factory.createServerSocket(8081);

}                                                     



public void run() throws Exception {                 

while (true) {                                   

    /* wait for a connection from a client */

    //Socket s = dServerSocket.accept();

    SSLSocket s = (SSLSocket)serverSocket.accept();

    /* then process the client's request */

    processRequest(s);                           

}                                                

}
```

Seems mostly fine, I run the server as follows:

```
java -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=com/learnsecurity/keystore.jks -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=123456 com/learnsecurity/SimpleWebServer
```

However, when I send a request to `https://localhost:8081` from Firefox, the server bombs out on me with this junk:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: bad_certificate
at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:154)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(SSLSocketImpl.java:1796)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1039)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.waitForClose(SSLSocketImpl.java:1574)
at sun.security.ssl.HandshakeOutStream.flush(HandshakeOutStream.java:122)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.sendChangeCipherSpec(Handshaker.java:705)
at sun.security.ssl.ServerHandshaker.sendChangeCipherAndFinish(ServerHandshaker.java:1297)
at sun.security.ssl.ServerHandshaker.clientFinished(ServerHandshaker.java:1257)
at sun.security.ssl.ServerHandshaker.processMessage(ServerHandshaker.java:244)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:609)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:545)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:978)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1223)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:838)
at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read(AppInputStream.java:94)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:282)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:324)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:176)
at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184)
at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:153)
at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:316)
at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:379)
at com.learnsecurity.SimpleWebServer.processRequest(SimpleWebServer.java:62)
at com.learnsecurity.SimpleWebServer.run(SimpleWebServer.java:45)
at com.learnsecurity.SimpleWebServer.main(SimpleWebServer.java:178)
```

I generated the certificate by following this tutorial:
http://www.sslshopper.com/article-how-to-create-a-self-signed-certificate-using-java-keytool.html

I've been searching around trying to find a resolution, but I've had no luck.  I'm thinking since the server IS running that it's something to do with the certificate.  Could someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I'm not sure WHAT the hell happened here, but I somehow magically fixed it.

I wanted to see what was causing the exception, so I wrapped `processRequest()` with a try catch for a `SSLHandshakeException`.  Suddenly, Firefox is yelling at me that the cert is untrusted (good sign).  So I add the certificate from the server and all of a sudden the connection works.  I close Firefox and try again, now it's broken again because of a NullPointerException.  Ok, so I wrap my request parser with a NullPointerException try catch..now it's working with no problems.  I don't even--can someone explain this madness?

Answer (score 1):

Your server is fine and it is ready to accept SSL connections from clients which it "trusts" that means whose certificates are available in the keystore of your server. And, in the above case, this is not true, because certificates in your FireFox are not listed in your server's keystore as trusted. So export your Firefox certificates and import them in your server's keystore as trusted certificates.

[How to export certificates from FireFox](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/842394)

[How to export certificates from Firefox 2](http://www.ngs.ac.uk/use-ngs/exportfrombrowser)

Comment: Hang on, I'm a bit confused now.  I was under the impression that the Server has to send its cert to the client, not the other way around?  In any case, I don't actually have any certificates listed in Firefox.